# SSL security error

Tags: sql-server-2005

What would the reason of getting the following error?

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind:

1. The name specified for the SQL Server (sqlserver.mydomain.com) does not match the name on the certificate (sqlserver.mydomain.net, for instance).
2. The certificate is issued by a certificate authority the client doesn't trust.

Are either of these the case?

Comment: Could be quite a few other causes.  The built-in SQL provider seems to return messages that are vague.  I've seen more descriptive messages using the SQL Native Client.

Comment: True, but these are the usual two suspects to check for first.

Comment: We are not using any certificates for web server and SQL server.